# Sql Server: Linked server to Informix database

Tags: sql-server, informix, linked-server

I have a Linked Server pointing to Informix DB. Using this linked server, I am writing a SQL query to fetch the data and load it into a SQL table.

But there are some tables exist which is throwing datatype overflow error. For a table I identified the column and the record which is causing the issue. 
Could not convert the data value due to reason other than sign mismatch or overflow.

If I exclude this column or the specific record, my SELECT statement returns the result without any issue. I analyzed this column which is Char datatype; I obtain an error when there are certain characters (€ or š character) in the field.

Below is the script that I used to create the Linked Server:

```
DECLARE @provider NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @provider = N'Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};'

`+` N'SERVICE=1526 ;' --Informix service name

`+` N'PROTOCOL=onsoctcp ;' --Informix protocol 

--+ N'DB_LOCALE=en_US.819; CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.819;';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 

@server =N'LS_INFORMIX', --Linked Server system name 

@srvproduct=N'Ifxoledbc', 

@provider=N'Ifxoledbc', 

@datasrc=N'xxx@yyyyyy', --Informix Database 

@provstr= @provider;
```

I tried to remove the commentLine on 5th row, but I receive error 7303 (cannot inizializate Ifxoledbc).

Can someone help me?

Comment: The values for CLIENT_LOCALE and DB_LOCALE should match your client and database locale. The Informix libraries use those values to make a codeset conversion. If DB_LOCALE is not the same as you have in your database, it will not connect at all which may explain the failure during the initialization. 

If you have an "€" in your database, the codeset shouldn't be 819 (8859-1), it should be something else (e.g. 8859-15). Something that allows such character. 

If your database was created with "en_US.819", and you do have a "€" inside, then you have bigger problem.

Comment: This old tech note describes the issues having characters outside the allowed range, even if it was written for the ODBC driver, the same applies to the IfxOleDB provider: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21402358

Comment: I check the sever and the correct value are this:DB_LOCALE=EN_US.8859-1; CLIENT_LOCALE=EN_US.CP1252;' Now I view all tables but don't resolve my original problem.

Comment: On the server side run  (dbaccess->Info->Nls). That should tell you the locale of the database. If the codeset is 819 (which is the same as 8859-1) it means you may have characters not valid for a 819 database. When the Informix oledb provider finds the  "€" it complains as it's not suppose to be there, it won't be able to convert it to 1252.

Comment: On the server I obtain this:NLS Capabilities and Attributes
   en_US.819 Collating Sequence
   en_US.819 CType

Comment: well... have a read at that technote I put above, it explains why you are getting the error. The best solution is to fix the database (changing the locale) but that involves dbexport/dbimport the data.

Comment: It is not possible to fix the database. According to you there is an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could avoid the faulty codeset conversion using ODBC instead of OLEDB for the linked server and setting CLIENT_LOCALE to en_US.819.

Create the linked server using the ODBC driver with:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver 'ids1210_odbc', @droplogins='droplogins';;

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ids1210_odbc',
 @srvproduct=N'MSDASQL',
 @provider=N'MSDASQL',
 @datasrc=N'ids1210',
 @provstr=N'Provider=MSDASQL'

exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ids1210_odbc',false,'sa','informix','mypass'

select * from OPENQUERY(ids1210_odbc,'select * from systables')

select * from ids1210_odbc.stores7.informix.systables
```

"ids1210" is the name of the ODBC System DSN. Use the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator to create it.
Both CLIENT_LOCALE and DB_LOCALE in the Environment DSN should be set to "en_US.819".

It should work and allow you to retrieve the "fancy" characters from the database but, at some point, you should fix the problem and change the locale of the database to suit the data you have inside.